# how to copy the texts from a generated pdf table?

Tags: itext7

I used itext7, the code for creating the tables are very simple:

```
    float[] tableWidth = {75, 75, 75};

    Table table1 = new Table(tableWidth);
    table1.addHeaderCell("head \n1");
    table1.addHeaderCell("head \n2");
    table1.addHeaderCell("head \n3");
    table1.addCell("column 1");
    table1.addCell("column 2");
    table1.addCell("column 3");

    Table table2 = new Table(tableWidth);
    table2.addHeaderCell("head 1");
    table2.addHeaderCell("head 2");
    table2.addHeaderCell("head 3");
    table2.addCell("column 1");
    table2.addCell("column 2");
    table2.addCell("column 3");

    document.add(table1);
    document.add(new Paragraph("\n"));
    document.add(table2);
```

I created two tables, only difference: head in table1 is with new line "\n":

[image]

Till here not any problem. But my question is when I tried to select and copy the tables from the generated PDF file and paste to MS-Word for example, I got different result: head of table1 is copied in vertical sequence:

[image].

As in my pratical code, I have to use "\n" in the table head, with this the table was then not able to be copy-pasted correctly, any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As in my pratical code, I have to use "\n" in the table head, with this the table was then not able to be copy-pasted correctly, any clue?

Your assumption that table content in general can be copy&pasted from a PDF in a manner that respects the table structure, is wrong.

In the PDF the instructions drawing your table 1 are:

- Draw "head" at 38.5, 790.83
- Draw "1" at 38.5, 772.85
- Draw "head" at 113.5, 790.83
- Draw "2" at 113.5, 772.85
- Draw "head" at 188.5, 790.83
- Draw "3" at 188.5, 772.85
- Draw line from 35.75, 806 to 261.25, 806
- Draw line from 35.75, 765.04 to 261.25, 765.04
- Draw line from 36, 806 to 36, 765.04
- Draw line from 111, 806 to 111, 765.04
- Draw line from 186, 806 to 186, 765.04
- Draw line from 261, 806 to 261, 765.04
- Draw "column 1" at 38.5, 749.87
- Draw "column 2" at 113.5, 749.87
- Draw "column 3" at 188.5, 749.87
- Draw line from 35.75, 765.04 to 261.25, 765.04
- Draw line from 35.75, 742.05 to 261.25, 742.05
- Draw line from 36, 765.04 to 36, 742.05
- Draw line from 111, 765.04 to 111, 742.05
- Draw line from 186, 765.04 to 186, 742.05
- Draw line from 261, 765.04 to 261, 742.05

Thus, there is no immediate indication anymore that there is a table. A simple text extraction mechanism, therefore, goes ahead and extracts the strings as they are drawn, inserting a line feed whenever the *y* coordinate changes, not differentiating whether it goes up or down. The result is what you observe.

---

PDF has the *option*, though, to tag the drawing instructions with HTML'ish indicators. Using iText 7 you can activate the tagging mechanism in your `PdfDocument` instance:

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
pdfDocument.setTagged();
Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
...
```

*(Excerpt from [TablesToCopyAndPasteFrom.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/content/TablesToCopyAndPasteFrom.java))*

Now your table1 is copied&pasted to Word like this

```
 head1      head2       head3
column 1    column 2    column 3
```

as an actual Word table.

---

Unfortunately there still are some minor glitches, e.g. the space between "head" and the number vanished. I'm not sure who is to blame, iText, Adobe Reader, or Word.

---

**PS:** The glitch with the *vanishing space between "head" and the number* appears to have been fixed in the iText development version 7.0.2-SNAPSHOT in check-ins on January 27th.